# Find the closed form of a bijective fully differentiable function $h$ with the following property

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm looking for the closed form of a function $h:\mathbb{R}-\{0\}\to \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$ defined as

$$\exp(h(1/x))=h(x)$$

What I got so far is that $\dfrac{h'(1/x)}{h'(x)}=\exp\left[-h(1/x)\right]$ where $h'(x)=\dfrac{dh}{dx}(x)$. But I do not know how to follow from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $h(1/x)=\ln(h(x))$. Replacing $x$ by $1/x$, this gives:
$$h(x)=\ln(h(1/x))=\exp(h(1/x))$$

Now, the equation $\ln(t)=\exp(t)$ has no real solution...

Answer (score 0):

Since h(1/x)=exp(h(x)) we get h(x)=exp(h(1/x))=exp(exp(h(x))). Hence the range of h is contained in the solution set of the equation y=exp(exp(y)). This set is countable, it has no limit points so h is necessarily a constant on $(0,\infty)$ and $(-\infty,0)$. In fact the solution set of above equation is a singleton set, so h is a constant. There is no bijective continuous function satisfying the given functional equation.

Comment: This is not your first post on MSE, you should use LaTeX syntax.